# Install application shortcut on user's homescreen

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have an app for `Android` built with `PhoneGap Build`.

How can I make it `install a shortcut` on the user's home-screen when the application installs successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new plugin which does this:

https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/265